# Filtering rows by years; AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

This code is used to show which delivery's are late, prints out the "Material" number associated with it, and shows how many days late the delivery was. My issue now lies with trying to filter the data set to only read a specified range of time; in my following code I attempted to filter the data from 2017 to 2018, however I am receiving an error ( listed below the block of code). How can I filter rows to show only a specified range of time, while conducting the same analysis: which is to see which Material part numbers had a late delivery and to see how many days late it was( without running into an error )

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta



df = pd.read_csv('otd.csv')

diff_delivery_date = []
date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'
df2 = df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year >= 2017) & (df['Delivery Date'].dt.year <= 2018)]



for x,y,z in zip(df2['Material'], df2['Delivery Date'], df2['source desired delivery date']):
    actual_deliv_date = datetime.strptime(y, date_format)
    supposed_deliv_date = datetime.strptime(z, date_format)
    diff_deliv_date = supposed_deliv_date - actual_deliv_date
    diff_delivery_date.append(diff_deliv_date)

df['Diff Deliv Date'] = diff_delivery_date

print(df2)
```

Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\khalha\eclipse-workspace\Python\Heyy\Code.py", line 13, in <module>
    df2 = df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year >= 2017) & (df['Delivery Date'].dt.year <= 2018)]
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4372, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 133, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 325, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Dummy csv:
[Image of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vq4w.png)

```
Material    Delivery Date   source desired delivery date
3334678 12/31/2014  12/31/2014
233433  12/31/2014  12/31/2014
3434343 1/5/2015    1/5/2015
3334567 1/5/2015    1/5/2015
546456  2/11/2015   2/11/2015
221295  4/10/2015   4/10/2015
```

Sample dataframe:

```
Deliveryvalue = df2['11/31/2014', '11/31/2017', '11/31/2018']
Desiredvalue = df2['12/31/2014', '12/21/2017', '12/11/2018']
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the DataFrame, that can be used (not an image)?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, Okay, how should I provide this sample of a dataframe, my apologies new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Something like pd.DataFrame(data=[[3334678, '12/31/2014', '12/31/2014']],
             columns=['material', 'delivery-date', 'source-desired-delivery']), where the values reflect the real values and types of your data.

Comment: Is the 'otd.csv' separated by commas or whitespaces?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, I believe its comma separated, when I print a list of some sort, there is commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this answer I'm assuming your data has the following format:

```
Material,Delivery Date,source desired delivery date
3334678,12/31/2017,12/31/2017
233433,12/31/2017,12/31/2017
3434343,1/5/2017,1/5/2017
3334567,1/5/2017,1/5/2017
546456,2/11/2017,2/11/2017
221295,4/10/2017,4/10/2017
```

So, assuming that you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('odt.csv')

df['Delivery Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Delivery Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['source desired delivery date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['source desired delivery date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df2 = df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year >= 2017) & (df['Delivery Date'].dt.year <= 2018)]
df2['Diff Deliv Date'] = df2['Delivery Date'] - df2['source desired delivery date']

print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
   Material Delivery Date source desired delivery date Diff Deliv Date
0   3334678    2017-12-31                   2017-12-31          0 days
1    233433    2017-12-31                   2017-12-31          0 days
2   3434343    2017-01-05                   2017-01-05          0 days
3   3334567    2017-01-05                   2017-01-05          0 days
4    546456    2017-02-11                   2017-02-11          0 days
5    221295    2017-04-10                   2017-04-10          0 days
```

**Notes**

After loading the data the types of the columns where the following:

```
Material                         int64
Delivery Date                   object
source desired delivery date    object
```

You can check if yours are those. Then you need to convert the `'Delivery Date'` and `'source desired delivery date'` to datetime, this is done in:

```
df['Delivery Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Delivery Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['source desired delivery date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['source desired delivery date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Then simply filter the data and compute the difference. Also I changed:

```
df['Diff Deliv Date'] = diff_delivery_date
```

to `df2` given than your code prints `df2` in the end.